# Is there a reference that explains the literal meaning and etymology of the names of the Hebrew months?

Tags: names, calendar, etymology, months

Is there a reference that explains the literal meaning and etymology of the names of the Hebrew months? I am looking for something that explains both the common Babylonian names as well as the Tana"ch names such as Aviv, Bul, Eitanim and Ziv. I can't think of others mentioned in Tana"ch.

Comment: Do you want academic explanations of the sources for the Babylonian names - ex. "Thursday comes from the god 'Thor'" - or only Jewish traditional explanations?

Comment: Have you checked Jewish Encyclopedia and Encyclopedia Judaica?

Comment: The Benei Yissaschar does this for each month, though it's all though chassidic thoughts, not a scholarly etymology

Comment: This is the most helpful site I've found for the months:  http://www.yashanet.com/library/hebrew-days-and-months.html

Comment: Think the only thing missing on that site is a reference to:  "the month Tzach. ... to that month (which would mean that it corresponds to Sivan, harvest time)." - which I find interesting.